# Remove Duplicate Pages so only original exists

Tags: pages

Basically I have around 4000 pages on my wordpress site and I have identified 1320 are duplicates.

I know I can go select each and every one manually and then bulk move them to the trash etc but does anyone know of a more time efficient way to do this?

Perhaps a MYSQL query to delete all the duplicates pages?

An example of the urls is as follows:

(Original)

/page/

(Duplicate)

/page-2/ and sometimes even /page-3/

There must be a way to mass delete all pages with the added -2 or -3

Thanks for any and all help.

Some added information

I created pages depending on locations and I've just realised that I have pages such as

Berwick upon Tweed

and

Berwick-Upon-Tweed

I'd Ideally like to delete the pages with the - in the title as well

Comment: Are you sure that the pages with "-2" and "-3", etc., are all duplicate pages and not just duplicate titles?

Comment: yes they are all duplicate pages.

page-example and page-example-2 both exist unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

As you assure me that the post title is an accurate indicator of the "duplicate" status of the post, a little bit of SQL and [`wp_delete_post()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post) will do it:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID
  FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
  WHERE post_title REGEXP '^.*-[[:digit:]]*$'
  AND post_type = 'page'";
$del = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
foreach ($del as $d) {
  wp_delete_post($d);
}
```

As written, your duplicates will end up in the "trash", unless that is disabled. You can use...

```
wp_delete_post($d,true);
```

... to force deletion.

Based on a comment below:

> I created pages depending on locations and I've just realised that I
>   have pages such as Berwick upon Tweed and Berwick-Upon-Tweed I'd
>   **Ideally like to delete the pages with the - in the title**...

I can't help but think that that is a phenomenally dangerous thing to do, but the SQL is simple:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID
  FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
  WHERE post_title LIKE '%-%'
  AND post_type = 'page'";
```

Comment: It said there was an error with that code however I managed to come up with this...

`DELETE a.*
FROM wp_posts AS a
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
      FROM wp_posts
      WHERE post_type = 'page'
      AND post_status = 'publish'
      GROUP BY post_title
      HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
   ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
AND b.min_id <> a.id
AND a.post_type = 'page'
AND a.post_status = 'publish'
`

This managed to get rid of around 550 of the duplicates but for some reason there are still quite a lot of duplicate pages left

Comment: To be more specific I've narrowed down the problem.

I created pages depending on locations and I've just realised that I have pages such as

Berwick upon Tweed

and 

Berwick-Upon-Tweed

I'd Ideally like to delete the pages with the - in the title...

Comment: The code runs on my server. I tested it.

Comment: Sorry there might be some finger trouble from my end however I copy and paste your code into the SQL part of phpMyAdmin and it comes up saying MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$sql = "SELECT ID
  FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
  WHERE post_title REGEXP '^.*-[[:dig' at line 1

Comment: You are running a MySQL server that doesn't like my `REGEXP` syntax. The `LIKE` in the edit should work, but it does do something different.

Comment: Just to verify I'm trying the first code you posted, not the second one regarding the files with - in them so I tried 

$sql = "SELECT ID
  FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
  WHERE post_title WHERE post_title LIKE '%-%'
  AND post_type = 'page'";
$del = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
foreach ($del as $d) {
  wp_delete_post($d);
}

adding the LIKE

However still got an error about the syntax...

Thank you for your time and patients by the way I really do appreciate it!

Comment: What version of My SQL?

Comment: The version is 5.1.73-log from the query I ran (select version();)

Comment: Just me brain storming but would it not be possible to run a query to find all pages that have -2 or -3 added to the end of the url and just delete all the ones that have?

Comment: That is what the `REGEXP` code does. I don't know why you are getting an error with it.

Comment: I am running almost exactly the same version of MySQL. Don't delete with the MySQL statement. You have to worry about post_meta and other things. Delete with the Core function like I did.